# Unable to run Shell Script

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

Hi i am trying to run shell script from following code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class ScriptTest {
     public static void main(String[] args){


    BufferedReader stdErr=null;
    BufferedReader stdIn=null;
    try{   
    System.out.println("In Script");
    String[] commands= {"ls"};
    Process process  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/mobilityapps/testScript/testScript.sh");
    stdIn=  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));        
    stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    String inline= stdIn.readLine();
    String errline =stdErr.readLine();
    System.out.println("*Inline*"+inline);
    System.out.println("*Errline*"+errline);
    while(inline!=null){
        System.out.println(inline);
        inline=stdIn.readLine();
    }
    while(errline!=null){
        System.out.println(errline);
        errline=stdErr.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Process Exit Value: "+process.waitFor());
    }catch(Exception excp){
        excp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The script i am trying to call is

```
CURRDATE=`date '+%d%b%Y'`
TIMESTAMP=`date '+%H:%M'`
BASE_PATH=/mobilityapps/testScript
LOGFILE=${BASE_PATH}/logs_${CURRDATE}_${TIMESTAMP}.log
echo ${CURRDATE} ${TIMESTAMP}>>${LOGFILE}
```

All both the script and Java program are in the same directory.
When i run `testScript.sh` from `PUTTY` it runs fine

But when i run from `Java` program `Process Exit Value is 255`

Can anyone suggest the changes?

Comment: `Runtime..exec` Have you considered updating to `ProcessBuilder`?  Need to support 1.4 or before?

Comment: i am working with java6

Comment: Hi, should i upgrade to ProcessBuilder

Comment: The thing is.  Most use of `Runtime.exec` is by rank amateurs who fail to consume the streams, and hand it multiple arguments in a single `String`.  `ProcessBuilder` encourages multiple arguments & makes it easier to consume the streams (by offering to merge them).  OTOH In your example both output streams are consumed, and there is just 1 argument.  ..It is borderline whether it is worth it!  Though I just have a vague feeling you are better off using the latter API simply because Oracle would care if they got a bug report about it.  ;)

Comment: thnx but for your reply but i am unable to comprehend much. Can you please ellaborate as i am new to Java

Comment: OK - stick with `Runtime.exec`.  Let's not complicate things!  :)

Comment: but i am still not able to run the script successfully

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the path

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/mobilityapps/testScript/testScript.sh");
```

with

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./mobilityapps/testScript/testScript.sh");
```

If you just use / at the begining, it means that it's a absolute path.
Using '.' indicates that is a relative path.

Comment: my file is /mobilityapps/testScript/testScript.sh absolute path whereas i am executing it from /opt/java6/jre/bin

Comment: do you get any values for your `system outs`? They may have useful information for debugging.

Comment: also do you have `+x` bit (aka execute bit) set for the `shell script`?